# Lost the Scene file

Tags: unity-game-engine

Today I opened my project as usual and I had an empty scene, the main scene didnt load, I also cant find it using the inspector search. So I went to my backup projects to recover the main scene (had like 2 months of this project copies on my external HD) and I noticed that there are not any saved main scene on any of the backup projects from the last 2 months.

Is it possible that the main scene was stored in another folder or something? or how can I locate the scene?

Comment: how did you search for the scene?

Comment: Inside the project with the inspector searcher (by scene type) outside with *.unity also i am deep searching with recovery tools. But still I dont understand why there is not a single secene file in any of my project backups when i copied and pasted the whole project folder. Where did unity saved/loaded the scene during the last months? I cant understand.

Comment: It does seem odd, but it would be in the assets folder or below and it wouldnt have worked if it wasnt.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can only save your scenes inside the asset folder.
You could search the asset folder for any *.unity file.
In Unity itself you can't move it outside the asset folder, but with an OS explorer you could.
You can always search if you find the missing *.unity file anywhere else on your HD.
If you used GIT, you could check if your *.unity file is in the .gitignore.

Edit: Did you work in the samplescene or did you create a new one?
On default the samplescene is created in Assets/Scenes/Samplescenes.unity

Comment: Yep searched a lot and I dont find any scene. But how is possible that all the backups copied into my external USB hard drive also have no any scene? I copied all the project folder and I have been using the same folder for months.

Comment: @Arkshija Did you ever explicitly *save* your scene?

Comment: @Draco18s Yes I save the scene very often. On the external drive I didnt. I just copied and pasted the full project folder. But the file scene should be also on the USB HD and I dont have any in any backup for the last two months. Thats why my only conclusion is that new Unity versions use another type of scene save system or my project scene was in another place and not inside the Assets folder. Did some fill searche sin my PC but nothing...

Comment: *`my only conclusion is that new Unity versions use another type of scene save system`* It doesn't.

Comment: @Arkshija this is a long shot since it should only be there if unity crashed and you didn't reopen in after, but can you look if there is a temp folder on your USB? More specifically 'Project'/Temp/__Backupscenes, if this folder exists you can copy the unity file 0.backup to your projects scene folder and rename it to 'anything'.unity